# Copying from range of cells in csv to excel error

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am migrating from vba to python and am trying to copy a range of columns 2-11 to an existing workbook 2-11.  It tends to work other than throw a:

`Exception: Invalid Excel character '[]:*?/\' in sheetname`

Python code :

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
workbook = Workbook('C:/Users/AWA/AA1.xlsx')

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('C:/AWA/AA.csv')):
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(os.path.splitext(csvfile)[0]) 
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col) 
    workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use so low level method. I recommend using pandas for such migration:

```
data=pandas.read_excel('myfile.xlsx',sheetname=None)
fa=data["Sheet 1"]
```

All your sheets will become arrays in one instruction. for that you must install [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd).

Comment: Good point.  I have tried to do a simple read from csv to write to excel https://pastebin.com/XQbtDinV though it tends to give pd not defined/